# Can't extend the function to continuous

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, discontinuity

I have code:

```
Am0[ω_] := Abs[H[I*ω]]
Am[ω_] := Piecewise[{{Limit[Am0[ω], ω -> 0], ω == 0}, {Am0[ω], ω!= 0}}]
Limit[Am0[ω], ω -> 0]
Am[0]
```

Function `Abs[H[I*ω]]` has [0/0]-uncertainty at ω = 0, and I tried to extend it to continuous funstion. However, I get errors like:

```
Infinite expression 1/0 encountered
```

and so on:
[image: Errors]

At the same time, `Limit[]` works correctly.

Why this doesn't work and how do I realize extension? Thanks in advance.

**Update.** More code:

```
{R, L, C1, Rl, T, Um} := {500, 0.2, 2*10^(-10), 10^3, 10^(-3), 10};
{ZR, ZL[s_], ZC[s_], ZRl} := {R, s*L, 1/(s*C1), Rl};
H[s_] := (((ZC[s] (ZL[s] + ZRl))/(ZC[s] + ZL[s] + ZRl))/(ZR + ((ZC[s] (ZL[s] + ZRl))/(ZC[s] + ZL[s] + ZRl))))*(ZRl/(ZL[s] + ZRl))
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for the function `H`?  The answer may depend on its properties.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Sure! Here it is.

Comment: `Am[0]` ends up computing `Limit[…, 0 -> 0]` which is nonsense.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you! You're right, I should have written something like

`Am[ω_] := Piecewise[{{Limit[Am0[ω0], ω0 -> 0], ω == 0}, {Am0[ω], ω!= 0}}]`.

Comment: Doesn't your last comment fix the problem?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Actually, it did.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use exact values for the constants.

```
{R, L, C1, Rl, T, Um} = {500, 1/5, 2*10^(-10), 10^3, 10^(-3), 10};
{ZR, ZL[s_], ZC[s_], ZRl} := {R, s*L, 1/(s*C1), Rl};
```

Use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) and [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) in the definition of `H`

```
H[s_] = (((ZC[s] (ZL[s] + ZRl))/(ZC[s] + ZL[s] + 
         ZRl))/(ZR + ((ZC[s] (ZL[s] + ZRl))/(ZC[s] + ZL[s] + ZRl))))*(ZRl/(ZL[
        s] + ZRl)) // Simplify

(* 50000000000/(75000000000 + 10005000 s + s^2) *)
```

Assuming `ω` is real

```
Am0[ω_] = Abs[H[I*ω]] // ComplexExpand

(* 50000000000/Sqrt[100100025000000 ω^2 + (75000000000 - ω^2)^2] *)

Am0[0]

(* 2/3 *)
```

Consequently, there is no need to use [`Limit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html) or to define `Am`

Comment: Thank you! But how does it work? I mean, how does `ComplexExpand` remove [0/0]-uncertainity, and why this uncertainity occures at all? Mathematical (not Mathematica) formula of `|H(iω)|` seems like `√( aω^4 + bω^2 + c )/( ω^4 + eω^2 + g)`, and `|H(0)| = √(c)/g`. Mathematically, there is no uncertainities...

Comment: `ComplexExpand` does not remove the division by zero. Is is just to provide a purely real representation which avoids any potential problems with imaginary artifacts if the imaginary parts don't numerically cancel perfectly. The division by zero is eliminated by simplifying the expression for `H[s]`. Compare the form of `H[s]` for each approach. With the initial approach `H[s]` evaluates to `5000000000000/((500 + (
     5000000000 (1000 + 0.2 s))/((1000 + 5000000000/s + 
        0.2 s) s)) (1000 + 5000000000/s + 0.2 s) s)` Simplifying this expression removes the division by `s`